# How to enable HDRI support for ImageMagick in Ubuntu?

Tags: imagemagick

I have installed ImageMagick through `apt-get` in Ubuntu 12.04. Now I need to enable HDRI support for my ImageMagick scripts. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You should run

```
convert -list configure | grep FEATURES
```

If the result does not list HDRI, then you need to get a different build of ImageMagick. Your current one will not support it (it cannot be "added in" by the simple change of a local configuration setting).

Either build it yourself from sources, or ask your Ubuntu package maintainer in the most friendly way you can to provide an alternative build.

It's possibly still disabled in Ubuntu because the ImageMagick developer themselves call it an "experimental feature".